# ruby on rails relationship not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to access all relations beetween two models: Serie has multiple categories and multiple categories can be in diferent series. Is a many to many relationship.

I try to do the following:

```
class SeriesController < ApplicationController

   def category
      @category = params[:category]
      @series = []

      Serie.all.each do |serie|
         @serie.categories.all.each do |cat|
            if @cat.category == @category
               @series << @serie
            end
         end
      end
   end

end
```

Rails throws me that exception:

```
undefined method `categories' for nil:NilClass
```

Here are the models:

```
class Serie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :types
  has_many :categories, through: :types
end

class Type < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :serie
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :types
  has_many :series, through: :types
end

class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
     create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :category
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :types do |t|
      t.references :serie, index: true
      t.references :category, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know why this doesn't work.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Serie.all.each do |serie|
  @serie.categories.all.each do |cat|
     if @cat.category == @category
       @series << @serie
     end
     # ...
```

to

```
Serie.all.each do |serie|
  serie.categories.all.each do |cat|
     if cat.category == @category
       @series << serie
     end
     # ...
```

because there a local variables `serie` and `cat` defined in the blocks, but no instance variables `@serie` or `@cat`

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up your variables in your create method.  You reference `@serie` which is set to equal [] so in the each it is empty, the variable you create there is `serie` so use that.

```
....
      Serie.all.each do |serie|
      serie.categories.all.each do |cat|
        if cat.category == @category
           @series << serie
        end
     end
  end
```